# "Error [GUILD_VOICE_CHANNEL_RESOLVE]: Could not resolve channel to a guild voice channel." When using .setChannel()

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was updating my voice manager bot to discord.js v13 and ran into this error:

`Error [GUILD_VOICE_CHANNEL_RESOLVE]: Could not resolve channel to a guild voice channel.`

What my (full) code does is: An user joins a vocal channel, when he joins another vocal channel will be created and he'll be moved into that new channel, here's the function that triggers the error:

```js
const createChannel = async (name, NewChannel, NewMember, parente, limit) => {
  NewMember.guild.channels
    .create(name, {
      type: "voice",
      parent: parente,
      userLimit: limit,
    })
    .then(async (channel) => {
      channel.setPosition(NewChannel.position + 1);
      await NewMember.setChannel(channel.id);
    });
};
```

Comment: How do you *call* the function? That is an important part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think so. i call it like that: ``await createChannel(` Vocale da 2 #${channelLimits.maxTwoCounter + 1}`, NewChannel, NewMember, config.parent, config.maxtwo_limit);``

Answer (score 2):

I did some research, after the update to discordjs v13, they changed the channel type when you run the `.create()` method, if you want to create a voice channel now you can't write like in v12, instead you'll need to write like this:

```js
.create(name, {type: "GUILD_VOICE"})
```

If you need to create another type of channel, go to this link and check the "type" parameter from the properties list: [DiscordJS guide website](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/typedef/GuildChannelCreateOptions).